# Grails unable to resolve Apache Camel component when using the Routing 1.2.2 plug-in (it wants a .zip when it's a .jar that is needed)

Tags: grails, maven, apache-camel

This is my first question, so please be gentle.

I'm trying out Apache Camel in a Grails 2.0.3 project using the Routing 1.2.2 plug-in.  I've followed the instructions on the plugin page, and am able to successfully execute a simple route:

```
from('seda:input').to('stream:out')
```

However, when I try to do a route using another component (jetty in this case), I add

```
runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-jetty:2.9.2"
```

to my BuildConfig.groovy file, per instructions on the plugin page, but I get the following error:

```
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

    :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.apache.camel#camel-jetty;2.9.2!camel-jetty.zip

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

It's really a jar file that it should be getting, but I don't see a way to specify that.  Any ideas?

By the way, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.1.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which section did you add the dependency in?  It looks like you added it under:

```
plugins {
}
```

but you should add this under (a guess at the dependency so you might need to change this)

```
dependencies {
    runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-jetty:2.9.2"
}
```

Comment: And mark it as the correct answer too please so others know this, thanks! :)

Comment: @HenrykKonsek: sorry, I didn't know I could do that.

Comment: @Steve:  This is really showing how much of a n00b I am, but how do I mark it as the correct answer besides just accepting it?